# Styling GTK app with CSS3

Tags: css, gtk

Plain and simple:

Is it possible to style GTK3 <strike>(2 and/or< 3)</strike>applications using CSS**3**?

Comment: Did you even check the links of other related posts? i.e. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457960/gtk3-css-with-gtknotebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Have a look at the bottom of GtkCssProvider doc](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkCssProvider.html)

It shows exactly what *is* supported (in Gtk3), everything else is not. i.e. `transition`,`boxed-shadow` and a lot more are.

Comment: Actually if you read through the source code there are some properties supported that are not mentioned in the documentation...

Comment: Time to file a patch for that page?

Comment: It's in my open source to-do queue. :-P

Answer (score 1):

GTK 2 and GTK 3 have completely different theming implementations. GTK 2 uses theming engines and `gtkrc` files. GTK 3 uses CSS for theming, and (at least partially) supports CSS 3.